# C# how to disable certain settings fields in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I create a windows task using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper. However, I don't know how to uncheck the following options in the settings tab:

- Stop the task if it runs longer than
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop

[image]

My current code:

```
public static void createNewDailyTask(string taskName,string appPath, string description){

using (TaskService ts = new TaskService()) {

    Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task t = ts.GetTask(taskName);
    if (t != null) return;

    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();

    td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;

    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = description;

    TimeTrigger tt = new TimeTrigger();

    // trigger every 5 min
    tt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    // Add trigger to the task
    td.Triggers.Add(tt);

    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(appPath));

    // Register the task in the root folder
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td);

    }

}
```

In the TaskDefinition class , there is a settings object. However I couldn't find the corresponding properties to uncheck the checkbox for the previously mentioned options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears those checkboxes can be controlled by the properties `TaskDefinition.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit` (of type `String`) and `TaskDefintion.Settings.AllowHardTerminate` (of type `bool`).

ExecutionTimeLimit is documented to be a string with an unusual format. It says to use `null` or `"PT0S"` to allow running indefinitely:

> The amount of time that is allowed to complete the task. The format for this string is PnYnMnDTnHnMnS, where nY is the number of years, nM is the number of months, nD is the number of days, 'T' is the date/time separator, nH is the number of hours, nM is the number of minutes, and nS is the number of seconds (for example, PT5M specifies 5 minutes and P1M4DT2H5M specifies one month, four days, two hours, and five minutes). A value of PT0S will enable the task to run indefinitely. When this parameter is set to Nothing, the execution time limit is infinite.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/tasksettings-executiontimelimit

([`TaskSettings` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/tasksettings))

Note: ExecutionTimeLimit may also be a `TimeSpan`. If that is the case, use `TimeSpan.Zero` for the value to disable it.

Comment: I looked for ExecutionTimeLimit  and I found it of type TimeSpan. If I am not mistaken TimeSpan is not nullable.  I will give it a shot and provide you with results. Thanks

Comment: I tested that  and it worked. However, with  ExecutionTimeLimit I used new TimeSpan(0); and it unchecked the box.

Comment: @Muhannad interesting, originally I assumed it was a TimeSpan but when I looked at the documentation (for a different language) it said string, and I was familiar with the XML format which is also a string. But I will update the answer.

Comment: TaskDefinition.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.Zero; worked for me.